# Where should I get the header files for an STM32 microcontroller?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I have [this](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f3discovery.html?sc=stm32f3discovery#overview) STM32F3 Discovery board, and I'm trying to flash a simple blink program to it. All of the examples I've found have several stm32*.h header files, such as this for an F4 Discovery board tutorial:

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "fm_stm32f4_led.h"
#include "fm_stm32f4_delay.h"
```

Where and how do I get the header files for my board? (STM32F3) I can't seem to find anything in the datasheet or documentation to point me at where to get them. Also, what would be a good source for examples and learning material?

Comment: These should all be part of your SDK. The CubeMX program is used to install the right SDK for your chip.

Comment: Header files alone are rarely sufficient. Most often you need the whole libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Lee Daniel Crocker mentioned all HAL libraries shipped with the STM32Cube initialization code generator. You can download it here:

https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html

Also you can simple download only the HAL library sources: [STM32CubeF3](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubef3.html), [STM32CubeF4](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubef3.html)

Moreover the header files *fm_stm32f4_led* and *fm_stm32f4_delay* are some custom implementations from your tutorial. The associated code is probably this one:
https://github.com/RoanFourie/STM32F4-DISCO-EMBITZ-Blinky/tree/master/STM32F407Disco/LED

Therefore there is no F3 header/source files for this example.
Anyway it should be easily reused or ported for the F3.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you have a STM32F3 discovery board this means that the `stm32`**`f4`**`xx.h` header is the *wrong* one. You'll need the `stm32f3xx.h`. Also tutorials for a F4 microcontroller will need to be interpreted to be useful for a F3. Some features of a F4 are not present on a F3.

You can download the headers/library for the STM32F3 from ST.com using a ST account. The page [you linked](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f3discovery.html?sc=stm32f3discovery#overview) to contains a section called *Embedded Software* which contains a link with the text: STM32CubeF3. Following through the redirections you'll get an opportunity to download the library by clicking: Get Software.

This contains a complete project structure for several boards.

You can also download [STM32CubeMX](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html). This "is a graphical tool that allows a very easy configuration of STM32 microcontrollers and microprocessors, as well as the generation of the corresponding initialization C code for the Arm® Cortex®-M core or a partial Linux® Device Tree for Arm® Cortex®-A core), through a step-by-step process." It allows you to generate new projects and lets you easily included required (or all) library files.

`fm_stm32f4_led.h` and `fm_stm32f4_delay.h` are header files created by [RoanFourie](https://github.com/RoanFourie/STM32F4-DISCO-EMBITZ-Blinky/tree/master/STM32F407Disco/LED) and are meant to target a F4 board. I suppose they are not that useful for you.

I can recommend [this tutorial](https://ese.han.nl/~harends/wpsite/?page_id=36) from an ex professor of mine. It is targeted at the F0 microcontroller and uses [Keil](http://www2.keil.com/mdk5/uvision/) but the general rules still apply. You'll have to figure the ports and pins out for yourself though.

Comment: Thank you, and I mentioned in my post that those headers are for an F4 and that I have an F3, and I'm looking for the F3 headers. That tutorial looks very helpful, and I'm looking forward to going through it! As an aside, what is the rational for requiring a GUI tool to download the headers and support files instead of a simple Apache web server? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Hey Kyle, you can also simple download only the HAL packages. Look for STM32CubeF3 downloads on the ST site.

Comment: Please read the second paragraph, it says where to download the raw headers. Including sample projects and the structure how they are used. `fm_*` headers for the F3 probably don't exist.

Comment: Cubemx is a handy tool to do peripheral configuration and assignment. As an asside it also creates projects with your choice of availability of libraries